# Old Permissions from other users

Tags: windows-7

I just formatted my system and I'm having some problems in cleaning up stuff.

I had 2 partitions, formated C: and left with D:

Installed Win7 and I want to delete some of these folders in D:, but it's denying me permission, altought I'm the admin.

How can I clear these old permissions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to take ownership of the folder - taking ownership of the folder will allow you to grant yourself full control to that folder.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308421
How to take ownership of a file or folder in Windows XP

Comment: Thank you for the insight. But I'm using 7. I'll see if I can do that. Thanks!

Comment: did not worked. Any ideas?